# How to add a dash before text in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to add a dash before text. See image. How do I accomplish the dash before the text so that it looks like the image?

I have the following html

```
<div class="mrvl-ex-grid">
<article class="sample">
    <img src="/images/examples/PN9Xg.jpg" alt="Lorem Sum"><div class="mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu">
    <div class="mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn"></div>
    <label class="mrvl-ex-item-label">Video</label>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle with the CSS:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/weina67/0vozsjsb/
```

I got the hover menu and preview button to work (but not the dash at the middle. How would you add the dash at the middle between the preview button and label? See Image attached

[image]

The hover menu and label and preview button are shown when people hover over the image. Also I have to make the dash responsive (Looks good on 1024px, 1280px, 1440px). It has to show in the middle of preview button and label.

Note in the fiddle, you have to hover over the image to see the label and where I want the dash added.

Comment: You've used a precompiler for your CSS, like SASS or LESS... Can you please create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your actual output CSS?

Comment: @Abhitalks, thanks for correcting - I've edited :-)

Comment: Or could you post it as a Stack Overflow Snippet? Much easier to answer with. Its the document icon with `<>` in it. And is the solution you are looking for the `:before` pseudo element?

Comment: Use psuedo :before or :after unless you need to support < IE8

Comment: Here's the JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/weina67/0vozsjsb/

Answer (score 5):

If you want an ACTUAL dash, you could try something like this:

```
.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:after {
    display : block;
    text-align : center;
    font-size : 4em;
    margin : 20px auto;
    color: #fff;
    content: "—";
}
```

For a demo, here's [**a Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vozsjsb/4/)!

Comment: that works, but is there a way to get it in the middle (vertically centered) between the preview button and label at all screen sizes.

Comment: @KotYat: Just play around with the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the :before pseudo selector you can create an simple element before anything you want.

Example code:

```
article.sample:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

This creates a 75% width dash before your sample.

```css
 .mrvl-ex-grid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

article.sample:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(6, 158, 173, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu .mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn {
  background-image: url(../images/icon-glass-lt.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 25%;
  background-size: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu .mrvl-ex-item-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:hover .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:hover img {
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mrvl-ex-grid">
<article class="sample">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97500&w=200&h=200" alt="Lorem Sum"><div class="mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu">
    <div class="mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn"></div>
    <label class="mrvl-ex-item-label">Video</label>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

Click here for the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0vozsjsb/2/

Comment: I'de like to add that this is not actual an element _before_ this element, but an element _before the content_. Just mentioning it, as its something you need to keep in mind if you are going to use positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a div, with white background?

### **Demo :**

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(6,158,173,0.85);
}

.longdash {
    padding : .2em 0 0 0;
    width : 5em;
    margin : 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="longdash"></div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7zykhg5j/)!

---

## Note :

If you don't want an empty element, you could also use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element.

### **Demo :**

```css
body {
    background-color: rgba(6,158,173,0.85);
}

.mrvl-ex-grid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(6, 158, 173, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu .mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn {
  background-image: url(../images/icon-glass-lt.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 25%;
  background-size: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu .mrvl-ex-item-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:hover .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:hover img {
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:after {
    display : block;
    width: 5em;
    height : .1em;
    margin : 50px auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="mrvl-ex-grid">
<article class="sample">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&txt=500%C3%97500&w=200&h=200" alt="Lorem Sum"><div class="mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu">
    <div class="mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn"></div>
    <label class="mrvl-ex-item-label">Video</label>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0vozsjsb/3/)!

Comment: Whilst this might work, using pseudo before or after elements will result in less markup, should be more consistent across browsers and also avoids using empty html elements, which are purely for styling.

Comment: @lharby : Fixed that!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply mimick it with a background?

```
.mrvl-ex-item-label {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="1" viewBox="0 0 50 1"><rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="1" fill="white" /></svg>') no-repeat 50% 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

I am using an SVG here because its a little easier to reason about (although a single white pixel image could be stretched using `background-size` and would probably takle up even less bytes in `base-64`.

```css
.mrvl-ex-grid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(6, 158, 173, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu .mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn {
  background-image: url(../images/icon-glass-lt.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 25%;
  background-size: 50px auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu .mrvl-ex-item-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 22%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="1" viewBox="0 0 50 1"><rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="1" fill="white" /></svg>') no-repeat 50% 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:hover .mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample:hover img {
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.mrvl-ex-grid .sample img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mrvl-ex-grid">
<article class="sample">
    <img src="/images/examples/PN9Xg.jpg" alt="Lorem Sum"><div class="mrvl-ex-item-hover-menu">
    <div class="mrvl-ex-item-preview-btn"></div>
    <label class="mrvl-ex-item-label">Video</label>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

It might be better to use a single-pixel `base64` string for the white line as its easier and widely supported, but I just find the SVG approach cool. Heres how it would like as a single pixel base64 data string:

```
.mrvl-ex-item-label {
    background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQIW2P8////fwAKAAP+j4hsjgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') no-repeat 50% 0;
    background-size: 100px 2px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

The advantage being that images are much easier to work with than SVGs and their unpredictable behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

Labels, as far as I'm aware, don't accept :before/:after pseudo-elements. Therefore, I propose simply adding a `<hr>` to your markup in the appropriate place (before the label), giving it whatever class name you'd like, and then apply the following styling:

```
.hr {
  width: 25%;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 1px);
  left: 37.5%;
  border: 0; // overrides standard <hr> styling
  background-color: white;
}
```

There are various enhancements you can make to this with preprocessors but hopefully it gives you the right idea.